# Any plans for a Documentation feature within SuperUser?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes, I come across information that I suspect is nowhere else on The Net and I think that posting it would be helpful to the community at large.  I ask because the information is more appropriate for SuperUser than for StackOverflow and I don't see any sort of Documentation feature.

Here is an example:

> At work, we use Lenovo T460s and p laptops and we were stumped as to
>   why, after successfully put them to sleep, either before or after
>   undocking, they would re-awaken a few seconds later!  It didn't always
>   happen but it occurred often enough that it was annoying.  No amount
>   of Googling or updating software solved the solution.
>
> Finally, one observant person discovered that it was his inadvertently
>   moving his wireless mouse that caused the laptop to re-awaken. 
>   Because we like to keep the mouse dongle connected to the laptop, the
>   solution was to simply avoiding moving the mouse, post-sleep, or turn
>   off the mouse, pre-sleep.

On the other hand, just tell me if I should simply post the question as if I didn't know the answer and then answer it myself.

Answer (score 3):

The self answer is definitely the correct thing here. [Its encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

For the moment, I'm not aware of any plans to extend documentation to SU. [It is still very much WIP in SO anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation?cb=1), and does not *quite* feel like the sort of thing that would fit into documentation IMO.

Presumably, if it happens, we'll get a heads up from a CM and I'll hopefully remember to update this answer.

Comment: It has occurred to me that it might be useful to import *all* the Unix man pages into a [SE] site, so we ([SU] and U&L, and occasionally [SO]) can link to a [SE] resource, decreasing the risk of link rot.  This raises questions: (1) Are there legal restrictions?  (2) How would we deal with multiple versions of software? (3) How would we deal with new versions that come out after we imported everything? (4) How broad a broom should we use?  (I.e., should we include software that isn't included in any major Unix/Linux release?  Should we include software that isn't free?)